# How do you get seasoned flaky meat?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

I am on challenge 10 of herbalist and I need the flakey meat.
Went on catching a northern pike which gives this meat.

The problem is that I can’t get the meat seasoned. When I keep the fish and choose to cook immediately it does not ask me to season or shows in the menu either.

The only thing I can do is stow it on the horse or cook which gives me plain flakey fish.

Am I missing something or am I catching the wrong fish?

Answer (score 5):

Press left or right on the D-pad to switch between the recipes. The seasoned versions aren’t shown in the list of crafting options unless you are already at capacity for the plain version of the meat.

Answer (score 2):

When catching a large fish which has flaky meat, you are given two options, Drop or Cook. If you select Cook, then you automatically cook a single piece of Plain Flaky Fish, but have no remaining pieces of Flaky Fish Meat to season. There is no way to break down fish into Flaky Fish Meat as can be done with other types of fish meat.

The solution will sound weird, but it works: Go to the beach and make camp. Keep the camp up, and walk over to the water. Catch a big fish, then walk back to your campfire. You will see the Drop option disappear. Select Cook. After the first piece, you can select Back to the recipe panel and season you 3 remaining pieces of Flaky Fish.